# Creating new theme in orchard with codegeneration module

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I was following the documentation on this [OrchardProject.net link](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Customizing-the-default-theme/). I opened have activated the CodeGeneration module and opened the command prompt at the root of the project (Orchard.Web) and write "bin/Orchard.exe" for running the commands. Till then everything is fine. Now when I try to run the following command, it gives me the below exception. The command is:

*codegen theme mishrajiTheme /BasedOn:TheThemeMachine /CreateProject:true /IncludeInSolution:true*

Below is the output of the command.

> Creating Theme
>   mishrajiTheme
>
> ### Error executing command "codegen theme mishrajiTheme"
>
> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter
>   name: startIndex
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified
>   argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name:
>   startIndex
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range
>   of valid values. Parameter name: startIndex]    at
>   System.String.Insert(Int32 startIndex, String value)    at
>   Orchard.CodeGeneration.Commands.CodeGenerationCommands.AddToSolution(TextWriter
>   output, String projectName, String projectGuid, String
>   containingFolder, String solutionFolderGuid)    at
>   Orchard.CodeGeneration.Commands.CodeGenerationCommands.CreateThemeFromTemplates(TextWriter
>   output, String themeName, String baseTheme, String projectGuid,
>   Boolean includeInSolution)    at
>   Orchard.CodeGeneration.Commands.CodeGenerationCommands.IntegrateTheme(String
>   themeName, String baseTheme)    at
>   Orchard.CodeGeneration.Commands.CodeGenerationCommands.CreateTheme(String
>   themeName)
>
> ---

What I am doing wrong here or It is a bug in Orchard code generation module.
Please guide. I am using Orchard 1.10 version.

Comment: When you say 1.10 do you mean exactly 1.10 or the latest 1.10.1 version? Is this a fresh install? Have you renamed your `Orchard.sln` file?

Comment: it is not the latest one. It is exactly 1.10. Yes, This is a fresh install. Also, I have not renamed `Orchard.sln` file. Also, I am working on it with visual Studio 2015 Community edition.

Comment: ok thanks, just investigating now

Comment: One thing that I have noted is that it has created the theme and it is also available from the dashboard theme menu to install, but it does not display inside the project solution. May be this will help you somehow to investigate the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by changing the `CodeGenerationCommands` Class in line 434 in Orchard 1.10. the line is :

```
 solutionText = solutionText.Insert(solutionText.LastIndexOf("EndProject\r\n"),   projectReference);
```

to this :

```
 solutionText = solutionText.Insert(solutionText.LastIndexOf("EndProject\n"), projectReference);
```

i don't know why by `\r\n` can not found the final EndProject and by changing that to  `\n` it works fine

Answer (score 1):

The line of code in question that has failed is this:

```
solutionText = solutionText.Insert(solutionText
   .LastIndexOf("EndProject\r\n"),projectReference)
   .Replace("GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution\r\n", 
       projectConfiguationPlatforms);
```

If `solutionText.LastIndexOf("EndProject\r\n")` doesn't find anything it will return `-1` - see the [MSDN docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy(v=vs.110).aspx).

It looks like that is then being passed to the `string.Insert` which is an invalid out of index.

The only thing that I can think is that your git client or however you got your hands on the orchard source has somehow changed the line endings in the file so it can't find the `\r\n`.

I'm guessing you are from the indian subcontinent, is your OS running a non-english language? I don't think that the `.sln` file localises fields like `EndProject` and I don't think Windows varies its newline character representation but something is going wrong here.

### Workaround Solution

This is the very last thing that the `codegen theme` command does, it has created everything else and just failed to add your project into the `Orchard.sln`. To get moving right now you can just add it to your solution:

1. In visual studio, open solution explorer window
2. Right click on your Themes solution folder
3. Click Add | Existing project
4. Navigate to the folder and select your new theme

### Potential Bug

It seems like there could be a bug here. Would you be willing to post your .sln file to me via email so I can investigate it further?